# Remove '\' from the string in IOS application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, html-escape-characters

I am getting a url as string from json response with backslash character. I want to remove the '\' character from the url. I build up the code but it is not working. The code is here:

```
 NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString* encodedString = [responseData stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Response ==> %@" ,encodedString);

       // here encodedString is a url which is showing crctly in output and need to trim the \ character.

       // NSString* str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"encodedString"];
       // str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"?" withString:@""];
       // NSLog(@"Response ==> %@" , str);

    encodedString = [encodedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""];
        NSLog(@"Response ==> %@" ,encodedString);
```

but I am not able to remove the characters.

Comment: What was the output ? can you show the NSLog ?

Comment: @Midhun MP  encodedString is printing twice without removing character(\)   Response ==> %22http:%5C/%5C/66.561.4.34%5C/Application%22 both space and (\) has to removed.

Comment: In the output of the NSLog all the `\ ` have been reomved so what is the problem

Comment: @rckoenes I need to remove space(%22) and backslash(%5C) from url to access that url further...

Comment: The you should remove the `%22` and `%5C` not `\ ` since there are n `\ ` in the sting any more. Or you should remove them before you `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`

Comment: @holex, I want to remove / and space from the string.

Comment: the `%22` it not the space... it is the quotation mark.

Comment: Try "\'" instead of "\".

Comment: Can you show the output of `NSLog(@"responseData=%@", responseData)` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to remove the spaces and `\` character, it is better to remove them from `responseData`.

```
NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

responseData = [responseData stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
responseData = [responseData stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""];
NSString* encodedString = [responseData stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
    NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\\"];
    encodedString = [[encodedString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString: @""];
    NSLog(@"%@", encodedString);
```

Hope this will help

Comment: I would not suggest this, this will create a lot of object is memory and wil be slower then a normal repalce.

Comment: **NO**, your string s should be foo\bar:baz.foo

Comment: Vaidya,Can you give me the final snippet to overcome the above issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this way;

Assuming your string contains a \, in string used double as for escaping the next \

```
NSMutableString *string=[NSMutableString stringWithString:@"hi this i\\s good"];
//NSMutableString *string=[NSMutableString stringWithString:encodedString];

[string replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@"" options:1 range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];

NSLog(@"%@",string);
```